# Creating new elements at runtime using Mithril

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mithril.js

Using Mithril, a Javascript framework, I am trying to add **new** elements **after** the initial body has been created and rendered.

Here is my problem in it's most basic form:

```
let divArray = [];
let newDivButton = m('button', { onclick: ()=> {
    divArray.push(m('div', "NEW DIV PUSHED"));
}}, "Add new div");

divArray.push(newDivButton);
divArray.push(m('div', "NEW DIV PUSHED"));

let mainDiv = {
    view: () => {
        return divArray;
    }
}

m.mount(document.body, mainDiv);
```

The code above will create a button and **one** line of text saying `NEW DIV PUSHED`. The button adds one new text element exactly like the 1st one. The problem here is that those additional elements are simply not rendered even if the `view` function is called. I stepped in the code and clearly see that my divArray is being populated even if they are not rendered.

One thing I noticed is that the initial text element (the one that is rendered) has it's `dom` property populated by actual `div` object. All the subsequent text elements in my array have their `dom` property set to `undefined`. I don't know how to fix this but I am convinced it is related to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mithril has an optimization built into the `render` lifecycle - [it won't re-render a DOM tree if the tree is identical to the last tree](https://mithril.js.org/components.html#define-components-statically,-call-them-dynamically).  Since `divArray === divArray` is always `true` the nodes are never re-rendering.

The simple, but non-ideal solution is to `slice` your array so you're always returning a new array from `mainDiv#view` and therefore, Mithril will always re-render the top-level array:

```
let mainDiv = {
  view: () => {
    return divArray.slice();
  }
};
```

The more *correct* way to do this is to map over the data, creating `vnode`s at the view layer, rather than keeping a list of vnodes statically in your module scope:

```
let data = ["Data Available Here"];
let mainDiv = {
  view: () => {
    return [
      m(
        'button',
        { onclick: () => data.push("Data Pushed Here") },
        "Add new div"
      );
    ].concat(
      data.map(datum => m('div', datum))
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you the answer, I understand your solution. I do have questions however:

How does `divArray === divArray` => `true` in the DOM tree's scope ? And isn't there a function to force mithril to re-render ? I guess `m.redraw()` also only renders if the DOM tree has changes ?

Comment: `m.redraw()` will do a diff and only redraw the changes. Defining the array of vnodes statically like this means mithril sees no changes and doesn't think it needs to redraw at all.